# AcquireTokenInteractive - Issue in MSAL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I am using **Msal** to `AcquireTokenInteractive` using Microsoft Graph SDK

**Simple code**

```
try
{
   string[] scopes = { "user.read", "files.read" };
    IPublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(appId).WithRedirectUri(redirectUri).Build();
    AuthenticationResult result = null;
    var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
    try
    {
        result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync();
    }
    catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
    {
        try
        {
            result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
        }
        catch (MsalException X)
        {
            ViewBag.ST = X.Message;
        }
        catch (Exception X)
        {
            ViewBag.ST = X.Message;
        }
    }               
}
catch (Exception X)
{

    ViewBag.ST = X.Message;
}
```

I am trying to get user's consent to allow my app to Read there data but when Code reaches `app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();` It just keeps loading infinitely.

Definitely doing something weird, any idea what it is?

Comment: Can you check with Fiddler or your browser's network tab that there's no redirection being made?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Adrian, there was a network proxy issue, my proxies was blocking the requests. I don't remember what the exact workaround was but I was able to fix it

Comment: Ali what was the solution for this I have similar issue

Comment: @Developer I honestly completely forgot what I did to fix it. I should have posted the fix, my apologies.

Comment: No problem worked it out, using  but the problem the tab is not getting closed automatically. I used as follows app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).WithSystemWebViewOptions(new SystemWebViewOptions()).ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken.None)

Comment: Glad you worked it out

Comment: Hi man, I'm experiencing the same issue. It just loads infinitely and doesn't popup the login. How did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to embed the view as follows:

```
  result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)                  
                    .WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
```